Holoviews panel explorer with mulitple file input doesn't render panel output
I'd like to plot multiple .csv source files of data into an Explorer GUI from holoviews.
Currently the code will open the browser, display the file selection drop down and the plot button, but when clicking the plot button, the CSV(s) selected just get dumped to the console as an error, with nothing rendering in the panel. I'm using PyCharm, not any form of notebook.
import io
import requests
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import panel as pn
from bokeh.plotting import show
from panel.widgets import FileInput, Button, CheckBoxGroup

hv.extension('bokeh')
pn.extension()

def plot_files(file_inputs):
    plots = []
    for file_input in file_inputs:
        if file_input is not None:
            # df = pd.read_csv(file_input) # this is a byte object, not path / string....
            s = requests.get(file_input, verify=False).content # added to get string from byteobject
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('UTF-8'))) # convert string to df
            # Create a plot for the DataFrame
            plot = df.hvplot.line(title=file_input.name)
            plots.append(plot)

    # Overlay all plots
    if plots:
        overlay = hv.Overlay(plots).opts(title="Overlay of Selected Files")
        return overlay
    else:
        return "No files selected or files are empty."

# file input widget
file_input = FileInput(accept='.csv', multiple=True)

# button for plotting
plot_button = Button(name='Plot Files')

# Create a placeholder for the plot
plot_output = pn.pane.HoloViews()

def update_plot(event):
    file_inputs = file_input.value
    plot_output.object = plot_files(file_inputs)

plot_button.on_click(update_plot)

layout = pn.Column("## HVPlot Explorer", file_input, plot_button, plot_output).servable()

#is .show not working with the explorer??
layout.show()

I've tried the above code and am not sure where I'm going wrong with it.
Any pointers or guidance would be really appreciated.
